# Meteor Mongo adding data to an existing collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I currently have the the collection "Plans" and it is made upon the creation of a form submit.  It inserts the following:

```
Plans.insert({
  location,
  address,
  date,
  time,
  notes,
  createdAt: new Date(), // current time
  owner: Meteor.userId(),
  username: Meteor.user().username,
  attendees: [
     {
        attender: [{
           user: String,
           attending: Boolean,
        }],
     },
  ],
});
```

Then, upon a click of a checkbox, I want a new `attender` object to be added to the `attendees` array.  So far I have tried to do:

```
'click .notattending'() {
  Plans.insert(
     {_id: this._id,
        attendees: [{
           attender: [
              {
                 user: Meteor.user().username,
                 attending: false,
              }
           ],
        }
        ]
     },
  );
},
```

However it isn't adding to the Mongo collection.  Is this the correct way to go about doing it?

Comment: you should be updating the document instead of inserting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to based on your schema.

```
Plans.update({ _id: this._id }, {
    $push: {
        attendees: { user: "", attending: true },
    },
});
```